# Why spring.cache.redis.key-prefix overrides @Cacheable(value="cacheValue")

Tags: spring-cache

In my application.yml, I defined a prefix for my cache keys:

```
spring:
  cache:
    redis:
      key-prefix: com.example.cache.
```

I also defined a cache value in the @Cacheable annotation.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository {
  @Cacheable(value = "users", key = "#criteria")
  List<User> findAllByCriteria(UserSearchCriteria critiera);
}
```

After the users got cached, I found out that the key which referenced the cached user list is
`com.example.cache.Criteria[]` instead of `com.example.cache.users::Criteria[]`.
If I left out the `key-prefix`, then the key became `users::Criteria[]`.

I am very confused about this behavior, how can I keep both the prefix and the cache value in the actual Redis key?